# ExceptionHandler doesn't work in controller

Tags: java, spring, exception

I want to change the return status of REST API request with spring.

I have created an exception class:

```
public class AutomatedActionValidatorException extends RuntimeException {

    public AutomatedActionValidatorException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

And a controller (commented my original code for testing the exception throwing):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/automated_actions")
public class AutomatedActionController {

    @Resource
    private AutomatedActionsService automatedActionsService;

    @Resource
    private AutomatedActionResponseService automatedActionResponseService;

    @Resource
    private AutomatedActionsSchedulingService automatedActionsSchedulingService;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save_and_run", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public AutomatedAction saveAndRunAutomatedAction(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                     @RequestBody AutomatedActionRequest automatedActionRequest) {
        throw new AutomatedActionValidatorException("");

//        AutomatedAction automatedAction = saveAutomatedAction(request, automatedActionRequest);
//        automatedActionsSchedulingService.runAutomatedActions(Collections.singletonList(automatedAction));
//        return automatedAction;
    }

    private AutomatedAction saveAutomatedAction(HttpServletRequest request,
                                               @RequestBody AutomatedActionRequest automatedActionRequest) {
        return automatedActionsService.save(automatedActionRequest);
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(value = AutomatedActionValidatorException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String handleAutomatedActionValidatorException(AutomatedActionValidatorException ex) {
        return ex.getMessage();
    }
```

And I still receiving 500 error code when calling to that endpoint.

From logs that I added, the `handleAutomatedActionValidatorException` method has ignored.

The response that I'm receiving is:

```
{
  errorMessage: "Unexpected error occurred.", data: null, success: false, 
  errorMessageKey: null}
  data: null
  errorMessage: "Unexpected error occurred."
  errorMessageKey: null
  success: false
}
```

Any idea what did I miss?

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the entire Controller class, the request you are sending and the response you are receiving? When I copy-paste your code in an empty Spring boot project, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Must be the request is failing before you are throwing exception

Comment: @StefK I debug it locally and arrived to AutomatedActionValidatorExceptionclass and still receiving 500 error code

Comment: I still can't reproduce this with the code provided in an empty setup. A suggestion, but I don't imagine that'll fix it: use the RestController annotation on your class instead of Controller. You'll be able to get rid of the ResponseBody annotations on your methods. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller . At least that makes your code simpler and less error-prone. Could you maybe provide the stacktrace you're seeing in your logs when this 500 occurs as well?

Answer (score 0):

(I am not sure if it would throw status code 500 if your `@RequestBody AutomatedActionRequest automatedActionRequest` is sent in wrong format by the client, you might want to comment out this code until it throws the exception you are waiting for

Edit: if the RequestBody would be in wrong format it would drop BAD_REQUEST. I your exception 500 must happen before your code would reach at this point)

If you don't do anything special in the ExceptionHandler maybe it would be enough for you to change your exception to this:

```
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason = "Bad request!")
public class AutomatedActionValidatorException extends RuntimeException {

    public AutomatedActionValidatorException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Please check if it is working. (put in comment block your exception handler)

If you get back the code 400, then you will know that the problem is in the exception handler.

These might help you:

https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-status-exception

Comment: Then most likely somewhere else happens the problem. You should share us your controller and any other method/class that is called from controller.